# Maximize Rectangle to fit application window QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need to make one `Rectangle` in QML maximize when user make double click on it. To do that, I define a `Rectangle` that contains `MouseArea` with `onDoubleClicked` handle. My question is: What I need to put in this handle to make Rectangle fit with app window maximized (not fullscreen, maximized).

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle

    MouseArea{
        onDoubleClicked:{
            // TODO HERE
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have added two states ("MINIMIZED" and "MAXIMIZED") and one reversible transition.

Comment: It's going to depend how the rectangle is positioned.  In other words, are you using coordinates and dimensions, or are you using anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no anchoring is set over our target `Rectangle`, you have a set of options to achieve what you want.

**1. States and transitions**

In this approach you define just *one* `State`: the expanded one. The other `State` is the default one, i.e. the `State` in which the `Rectangle` only covers a small portion of the window. A `Transition` is applied without `from` and `to` so that it is applied both when the `Rectangle` is expanded or shrunk down. Thanks to `State`s, we do not need to store previous coordinates as their values are *restored* when the default state is set back. Note that, in the following example, I've removed the `Math.random()` from `x` and `y` to avoid reevaluation and assignment of random coordinates every time we get back from "EXPANDED" state. Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: win
    title: qsTr("Playground")
    width: 620
    height: 420
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 20
        height: 20
        color: "black"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onDoubleClicked: {
                rect.state = rect.state === "EXPANDED" ? "" : "EXPANDED"
            }
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "EXPANDED"
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: 0}
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; y: 0}
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; width: parent.width}
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; height: parent.height}
            }
        ]

        transitions: [
            Transition {
                ParallelAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; duration: 350 }
                    NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "y"; duration: 350 }
                    NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "width"; duration: 350}
                    NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "height"; duration: 350}
                }
            }
        ]

        // randomization is applied with JS --> no properties binding
        Component.onCompleted: {
            rect.x = Math.random() * 600
            rect.y = Math.random() * 400
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Animations**

Simply put, define an animation to expand the `Rectangle` and one to shrink it down. Then call one or another depending on the position/size/whatever. You can write something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: win
    title: qsTr("Playground")
    width: 620
    height: 420
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: Math.random() * 600
        y: Math.random() * 400
        property int oldx; property int oldy
        width: 20
        height: 20
        color: "black"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onDoubleClicked: {
                if(rect.x === 0){
                    shrink.start()
                } else {
                    rect.oldx = rect.x
                    rect.oldy = rect.y
                    expand.start()
                }
            }
        }

        ParallelAnimation {
            id: shrink
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; to: rect.oldx; duration: 350 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "y"; to: rect.oldy; duration: 350 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "width"; to: 20; duration: 350}
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "height"; to: 20;  duration: 350}
        }

        ParallelAnimation {
            id: expand
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; to: 0; duration: 350 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "y"; to: 0; duration: 350 }
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "width"; to: win.width; duration: 350}
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "height"; to: win.height;  duration: 350}
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Behaviors**

A [`Behavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html) defines a default animation for a property change. In this approach we define an *homogeneous* set of animations for the different properties involved (`x`, `y`, `width` and `height`). In this way we only need to update the properties to the correct values, leaving to the `Behavior`s the task to animate the change. You can write something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: win
    title: qsTr("Playground")
    width: 620
    height: 420
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: Math.random() * 600
        y: Math.random() * 400
        property int oldx; property int oldy
        width: 20
        height: 20
        color: "black"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onDoubleClicked: {
                if(rect.x === 0){
                    rect.x = rect.oldx
                    rect.y = rect.oldy
                    rect.width = rect.height = 20
                } else {
                    rect.oldx = rect.x
                    rect.oldy = rect.y
                    rect.x = rect.y = 0
                    rect.width = win.width
                    rect.height = win.height
                }
            }
        }

        Behavior on x {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 450 }
        }
        Behavior on y {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 450 }
        }
        Behavior on width {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 450 }
        }
        Behavior on height {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 450 }
        }
    }
}
```

The first approach is, by far, the *cleaner* solution of all since it does not involve the usage of temp variables, like the second and third. `State`s automatically save/restore the status of the variables as the component moves among them.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Rectangle` size to reflect the window should be enough:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked:{
            rectangle.width = window.width //assuming your main window id is "window" 
            rectangle.height = window.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only work if `rectangle` is at position 0,0 in the window's coordinates.

Comment: It's pretty easy to adapt anyway, as the OP didn't make it clear how is its position.