# QML How to position a child outside it's parent

Tags: qt, qml

I am currently working on a Video/Stream Management program for my university. The body of my application is a `GridView`. I implemented a playbar for each video so I can use my playback functions specifically for each member of the `GridView`. The Problem now is `FullScreen`. I couldn't find a `showFullScreen()` function like the one from `Window`. Now I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460978/maximize-rectangle-to-fit-application-window-qml) and tried the first solution (States/Transitions) and it works the way it is intended except that I would need it to be able to go out of the parents scope.

Code:

```
GridView {
    id: mainGrid
    width: parent.width - (parent.width % cellWidth)
    height: parent.height
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    cellWidth: 300
    cellHeight: 300

    focus: true

    property bool newPlayStatus: true

    model: VideoModel {
        list: videoList
    }

    delegate: Component {
        id: videoDelegate
        Frame {
            id: videoContainer
            width: mainGrid.cellWidth
            height: mainGrid.cellHeight

            background: Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "black"
            }

            VideoDummy {
                id: video
                list: model.video
                videoUrl: model.url
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                focus: true
                playStatus: mainGrid.newPlayStatus

            }
            onChildrenChanged: {
                console.log("url: " + model.url)
            }

            Playbar {
                id: localPlaybar
                x: -12
                y: mainGrid.cellHeight - 42
                width: mainGrid.cellWidth
                height: 30

            }

            Connections{
                target:localPlaybar
                onToggleFullscreen: {
                    videoContainer.state = videoContainer.state === "EXPANDED" ? "" : "EXPANDED"
                }
            }

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "EXPANDED"
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: videoContainer
                        x: application.x
                    }
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: videoContainer
                        y: application.y
                    }
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: videoContainer
                        width: application.width
                    }
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: videoContainer
                        height: application.height
                    }
                }
            ]

            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    ParallelAnimation {
                        NumberAnimation {
                            target: videoContainer
                            property: "x"
                            duration: 350
                        }
                        NumberAnimation {
                            target: videoContainer
                            property: "y"
                            duration: 350
                        }
                        NumberAnimation {
                            target: videoContainer
                            property: "width"
                            duration: 350
                        }
                        NumberAnimation {
                            target: videoContainer
                            property: "height"
                            duration: 350
                        }
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I excluded some parts of my code because it would only made it harder to see the important parts. `application` is the id for the `ApplicationWindow`.

Currently this code isn't scaling everything to the size/position it needs to be but that is something I would do if the general idea would work.

The problem is that the `videoContainer` isn't able to go out of it's parents space. Is there any way to do it? I could open up a new `Window` with the needed qml parts and make it `showFullScreen()` but I do not believe that this is a nice solution is it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
onToggleFullscreen: {
    var i = videoContainer.mapFromGlobal(0,0)
    videoContainer.x = i.x
    videoContainer.y = i.y
    videoContainer.width = application.width
    videoContainer.height = application.height                   
}
```

With this I can resize and position it outside of its parent.